# How to show the loader and show after some processes is done?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to show the loader and make the all the processes wait until it reaches the final line. When it reaches the final line of the process, I just simply `resolve` it. So I can know it's done. Then, I use `then` to hide the loading. But I think the loader (which is in the root scope) is not showing because the loop is done faster than event handler. How can I achieve to show the loader and wait until the processes is done, then hide the loader using JavasScript or AngularJs?

```
$scope.$emit("loading.show");
let promise1 = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
       
        $timeout(function () { 
            if ($scope.rateCard.clientele !== undefined && $scope.rateCard.clientele.id !== 0) {
                for (var j = 0; j < $scope.gridData.length; j++) {
                    var value = $scope.rateCard.clientele.name;
                    var gridIndex = $scope.gridData[j].findIndex(function (x) {
                        return x.field == 'clientele';
                    });
                    if (gridIndex > -1) {
                        $scope.gridData[j][gridIndex].data = value;
                    }
                }

            }  
            //do a lot of stuff.. 
           resolve("success");
        }, 200);
    });

promise1.then(function (x) {
    console.log("finished");
    $scope.$emit("loading.hide");  
});
```

Comment: Try and increase the timeout length. 200 milliseconds is quite fast. It might be working as expected. Try and increase to 2000.

Comment: @tbone849 you mean there is no problem with the code but the delay of the time?

Comment: Could be the issue. The time delay might be so small you might not be seeing loader.